# Greps return nothing on text files generated by Wine programs

Tags: windows, grep, wine

I am a Windows 7 refugee working with Mint... but I am still using EAC (Exact Audio Copy) under Wine to rip my CDs. I have thousands of log files generated by EAC under Windows 7 and now some of them are generated in Linux but under Wine. I want to sort out the log files with the mention "There were errors". 
The command   `grep -wr errors *` does not return anything. Now if I cut and paste one log file in a text file using Gedit and/or Xed, the same command will output the result of this test file, but only those.
So clearly the Windows origin is to blame for the failure. The question is "is there an option to add to the command so that it works directly on Windows files,... without going through a conversion process like DOS2Unix or similar?"

[image: The test directory has two txt files one from EAC-Wine the second "identical" from a linux editor. The first file is considered as binary by grep so there is no result, the second works as it should.]
The test directory has two txt files one from EAC-Wine the second "identical" from a linux editor. The first file is considered as binary by grep so there is no result, the second works as it should

Comment: Add output of `file your_file` to your question.

Comment: This may be a Windows/Linux line end difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there were no answer, I post this one which, I agree, is not "Linux Style" but is nevertheless working and efficient. With the same two files as above we try again `grep -wr errors *` which gives only one file as result: Testlog.txt and should give both.

[image]

So, because I am using Wine for EAC, I can as well try to use a Windows style Grep program. Lots of them are not working, and we want,  at least, the program to be under a GPL licence.

A possible solution is using

> grepWin

[A window style grep](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html).

With it we get a good solution: the two files and maybe the reason of the grep failure we had because we see that both files, though they have the same content, have not the same encoding.
[image]

Practically I used the portable version of the program
grepWin-x64-2.0.2_portable.exe
and if the program works perfectly fine the first time, it always crashes the second time and will fail to work anymore if you do not take care of deleting the file

> grepwin.ini

which is generated (in the same directory as the program) by the program itself when you close it. Nothing Perfect!